# Подготовленные запросы PHP

Tags: mysqli, php

Использую `mysqli` функции. В частности `prepare`.
Так же прочитал, что бывает передача данных в БД как подстановка в запрос строковой заменой или данные передаются на сервер отдельно от запроса, после чего сервер их не подставляя использует в нужных местах.

Интересно как это настраивается в `mysqli` и если никак, то как оно происходит в нём.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$city = "Amersfoort";

/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $city);

    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* bind result variables */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $district);

    /* fetch value */
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

    printf("%s is in district %s\n", $city, $district);

    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

[mysqli::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: А когда случится `mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);` то данные придут к БД отдельно от запроса? Или они сначала подставятся в запрос, а к БД придёт строчка с подставленными данными?

Comment: @mike_live, насколько знаю, mysqli должен отдавать на обработку серверу, в PDO этим можно управлять, т.е. подстановук может выполнять как клиент, так и сервер.