# Как составить запрос, чтобы он хранился на сервере принимал дату/значения от клиента?

Tags: sql

Есть ситуация, когда запрос формируется в клиентском приложении. Пользователь вводит дату и по нажатию кнопки получает все записи из таблицы имеющие введенную дату.

Проблема, в том, что отправлять целый запрос серверу плохо, медленно и вообще нужно по возможности все запросы хранить на сервере.

Вопрос, как надо составит запрос, что бы он мог хранится на сервере при этом принимать дату (да и любую инфу) пришедшую из вне?

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE date =`...?

Comment: вы бы хоть язык указали, раз сервер, то, наверно, php? а значит нужны подготовленные запросы и можно посмотреть, например, [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/308263/5079) (или другие, их здесь куча). Или документация php: [раз](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepared-statements.php), [два](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Делаешь хранимую процедуру или вьюшку. И в качестве параметров передаешь дату.

Comment: На самом деле ничего не понимаю, вот и не посчитал нужным указывать язык, клиент десктопный, на C#, а сервер MySQL.

Дату передать с помощью функции?

Comment: @BlackOverlord Запрос не так много места занимает, его можно спокойно передавать из клиента. Вопрос лишь в том, что текст запроса всегда должен быть абсолютно одинаков. для этого надо использовать привязываемые переменые. Т.е. в тексте запроса вместо значения должен стоять `?` или другое обозначение которое вашему драйверу БД нужно. Хотя конечно в MySQL вы можете каждый запрос дополнительно обернуть в хранимую процедуру. потеряете гибкость, экономию получите копеечную, если вообще получите. (конечно если ваш MySQL не на другом сервере на канале 32 КБит)

Comment: И кстати, c запросами типа `select *` вы теряете гораздо больше на возврате сервером не нужных вам колонок, всегда указывайте какие конкретно колонки вам нужны.

Comment: Ну я для примера * написал. Сейчас нужно написать UPDATE для таблиц, то есть я правильно понял, знак "?" ставится, там куда должны прийти какие-либо данные из клиента?

Comment: "можете каждый запрос дополнительно обернуть в хранимую процедуру" - разве хранимая процедура это не есть запрос?